# How to return own field by attribute in python?

Tags: python, django, coding-style

I have a fields in django model:

```
class Norf(Models.model):
    foo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bar = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What is the best way for writing a following function?

```
    def get_bool(self, n):
        if n == 1:
            return foo
        if n == 2:
            return bar
```

Comment: your version looks pretty good to me. what's the problem you're having with that?

Comment: Problem is that i have 4 fields that looks not so pretty :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Norf(Models.model):
    BOOLS = [None, 'foo', 'bar']
    foo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bar = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_bool(self, n):
        return getattr(self, self.BOOLS[n])
```